# File upload with Yii's ActiveForm

Tags: file-upload, yii

I am trying to use Yii's ActiveForm to create a basic registration page with an image upload field.  However, I am running into problems.  I am using the following code to create the form tags:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'id'=>'activity_form', 
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
                                'stateful'=>true, 
                                'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'
                                ));
```

The above code produces the following error message in Yii:

Property "CActiveForm.enctype" is not defined

I've also tried:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'id'=>'activity_form', 
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
                                'stateful'=>true, 
                                array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')));
```

as well as:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'id'=>'activity_form', 
                                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
                                'stateful'=>true), 
                                array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')));
```

But neither of these work.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?  Can I use beginWidget to create a multipart form with file upload capabilities?  What's the format I should follow for this?  I can't seem to find any answers in the documentation or the forums.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Never mind.  I found the solution to this.  The trick is to use htmlOptions like so:

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'activity_form', 
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
  'stateful'=>true, 
  'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
));
```