# Unable to upload file to server with Yii

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I am building a YII web application and I'm trying to add a function where the user can upload a photo to the web application. I have searched for tutorials or documents on how to do this, but haven't had success.

I've been told that the easiest way to do something like this would be to store the actual image on the server in a flat file, and then store the path to the image in the database. I've created the model, called `Pictures` with the attributes: `Title`, `url`, & `description`.

Here is what the create action looks like in my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Pictures;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Pictures']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Pictures'];
        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'url');
        if($model->save())
            $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/granados/images/testimage.jpg');
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Here is my form:

```
    <?php
/* @var $this PicturesController */
/* @var $model Pictures */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'pictures-form',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'url'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'url'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'url'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Here is my model:

```
    <?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{pictures}}".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table '{{pictures}}':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $url
 * @property string $description
 */
class Pictures extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{pictures}}';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('title, url', 'required'),
            array('description', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            array('url', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png'), 
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, title, url, description', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'url' => 'Url',
            'description' => 'Description',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
        $criteria->compare('url',$this->url,true);
        $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Pictures the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. At this point, I'm not able to upload anything. When I submit a new form, I get a 404 error.

I'm completely lost at this point and not sure what to do. Here are the links I've tried so far:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607200/file-upload-with-yiis-activeform

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348887/show-uploaded-image-yii

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Pictures;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Pictures']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Pictures'];
        $model->url = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'url');
        if($model->save()) {        
            $fullImgSource = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/granados/images/'.$model->url;
            $model->url->saveAs($fullImgSource);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));    
        }   
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Improved: Block was missing after if statement.